# Tasks list not getting updated in real time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, real-time

**EDIT**: after running the same code in the `MainActivity` the `public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialog)` worked and everything got updated. so now the main problem is why its not running in other fragment?

The only difference I see is that on `MainActivity` the code is running in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

While on `Assignment` fragment its running in `public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`

---

My task list is not getting updated after adding a new task or updating an existing task unless I go from one fragment to another and then come back, but the delete task function does work and removes the task from the list without going to the other fragments.

Note: it did worked when the code was in `MainActivity`

I tried to log the `public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialog)`
but it didn't worked, so I assume maybe that's why...

Here is the code from my fragment:

```
public class AssignmentFragment extends Fragment implements DialogCloseListener {

    public static Context context;
    private FragmentAssignmentBinding binding;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private RecyclerView tasksRecyclerView;
    private ToDoAdapter tasksAdapter;
    private List<ToDoModel> taskList;
    private DatabaseHandler db;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentAssignmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        AssignmentFragment.context = getContext();

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
        db.openDatabase();

        taskList = new ArrayList<>();

        tasksRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.tasksRecyclerView);
        tasksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        tasksAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(db,this, null);
        tasksRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksAdapter);

        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(tasksAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(tasksRecyclerView);

        fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AddNewTask.newInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(), AddNewTask.TAG);
                }
        });

        
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialog){
        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Adding a new task:

Here I did tried to log the `public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)` but its also not responding.

```
public class AddNewTask extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "ActionBottomDialog";

    private EditText newTaskText;
    private Button newTaskSaveButton;
    private DatabaseHandler db;

    public static AddNewTask newInstance(){
        return new AddNewTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_task, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        newTaskText = getView().findViewById(R.id.newTaskText);
        newTaskSaveButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.newTaskButton);
        boolean isUpdate = false;
        final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            isUpdate = true;
            String task = bundle.getString("task");
            newTaskText.setText(task);
            if(task.length()>0) {
                newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
            }
        }

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        db.openDatabase();

        newTaskText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    newTaskSaveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                else{
                    newTaskSaveButton.setEnabled(true);
                    newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        final boolean finalIsUpdate = isUpdate;
        newTaskSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String text = newTaskText.getText().toString();
                if(finalIsUpdate){
                    db.updateTask(bundle.getInt("id"), text);
                }
                else{
                    ToDoModel task = new ToDoModel();
                    task.setTask(text);
                    task.setStatus(0);
                    db.insertTask(task);
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity instanceof DialogCloseListener){
            ((DialogCloseListener)activity).handleDialogClose(dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems `db.getAllTasks()` in `handleDialogClose` is being called before the db completes the insert task. Db insert is executed in non-ui thread and it's not instant.

Comment: Actually it's not being called at all, I tried to log it and it wasn't giving an output ,So any way to fix it?

Comment: Its asking for dialog in the parameter, what should I write?

Comment: Oh I missed that `handleDialogClose` is inside a fragment, I thought it's in the activity.  You can't manually invoke that - It's invoke by the system when the fragment is closed.

Comment: Calling a fragment method from another fragment is not safe. Each have different lifecycles.  
I suggest you use a `viewmodel` to update and read the db between fragments. Or better migrate to  [android room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) so your views can just subscribe to the db updates using live data and not to manually read every update.

Comment: well I just made a function inside the ```Assignment``` fragment and used it on a button, which worked, but when i called the same function from the ```AddNewTask``` fragment it gave error : ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.studenttaskmanager.Utils.DatabaseHandler.getAllTasks()' on a null object reference```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new task, you should write the following code immediately after;

```
tasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This code refreshes the database.

Comment: I tried that, It didn't worked

Comment: May be cause of this problem, call in onDismiss. Try change call from handleDialogClose method.

Comment: Can u explain it properly? I am new to android studio....